# Example of a group that can be written as a semi direct product of two NONabelian subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on some calculations for a conjecture that I have that involves looking at direct and semi direct product of finite groups.  So far the only groups that I have been able to use has been of the form $L=F\rtimes G$ where $F$ is normal in $L$ and $G$ is abelian.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a finite group $L$ that has the form $L=F\rtimes G$ where both $F$ and $G$ are nonabelian?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's relatively easy to come up with large collections of examples using non-abelian groups contained in other non-abelian groups, but I haven't found any immediate examples which can't be rewritten as direct products. Are you looking for examples which cannot be direct products (i.e. not directly decomposable)?

For example $A_n\rtimes A_k$ for some $k\le n$ where $A_k$ is identified naturally with a subgroup of $A_n$ and acts on $A_n$ by conjugation. This is isomorphic to $A_n\times A_k$.

Comment: Take any pair $G,H$ of non-abelian groups and $G\times H$ is an example (a trivial semi-direct product).

Comment: There is a universal embedding theorem which says that every extension of a group $G$ by a group $H$ (in particular $G\rtimes H$) is a subgroup of $G\wr H$. So $G\wr H$ (with $G$ and $H$ non-abelian) may be a particularly interesting example.

Comment: You could consider the holomorph of symmetric groups for example.

Comment: One example that may be interesting, or at least easy to work with: $Q_{8}\rtimes S_3$ which I think is isomorphic to $GL(2,3)$

Comment: This is one that I would I am thinking I need to use.  Thank you.